# How to specifify the class of an AWS client in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

In Java, for instance, we have a class that represents the SageMaker client class: `AmazonSageMakerClient`, but I couldn't find the equivalent for Python.

I was hoping to be able to do something like:

```py
from sagemaker import SageMakerClient
client: SageMakerClient = boto3.client("sagemaker")
```

I looked into the library code and docs but I couldn't find any references to such class containing the defined methods for that client. In fact, I couldn't find any classes for AWS clients like `s3`, `sqs`, etc. Are those hidden somewhere or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: boto3 uses a single factory method, so you use `import boto3; client = boto3.client('sagemaker')`, and then `client` is an instance of the `botocore.client.SageMaker` class.  You can check out the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html) for more details on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In boto3, there is basically 2 levels of objects avaialble:

1. A client
2. Actual objects like you are asking about

Take a look at [S3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html), and you will see that in addition to the Client object there are also other rich object types like Bucket.

It would seem that Sagemaker doesn't (yet) have this second level of abstraction available.

Answer (score 1):

To be more productive, and work with Python classes rather than Json, try to use the [SageMaker Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) whenever possible rather than Boto3 clients.

With Boto3 you have several SageMaker clients (As @anon said correctly):

- [SageMaker](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html) - Most of SageMaker features
- [SageMakerRuntime](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html) - Invoking endpoints
- SageMaker* - Other misc SageMaker features like feature store, edge manager, ...

Answer (score 0):

The [boto3-stubs](https://pypi.org/project/boto3-stubs/) library can help with this.

Install using the instructions for your IDE on the package page, and then install the specific type annotations for SageMaker.

```sh
pip install 'boto3-stubs[sagemaker]'
```

You should be able to see type hints for the `client` object (type: `SageMakerClient`).

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
```

If you need to add hints yourself:

```py
from mypy_boto3_sagemaker import SageMakerClient

def my_func(client: SageMakerClient):
    client.create_algorithm(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to do that. Here's some tricks I have used for a while:

```py
from boto_session_manager import BotoSesManager

bsm = BotoSesManager()
bsm. # <--- now it show you list of available client and it can do auto complete

bsm.s3_client # this is an Client object with explicit type hint

bsm.s3_client. # <--- now it show you list of available method

bsm.s3_client.put_object( # <--- now it show you list of available argument and their type)

bsm.s3_client # select the s3_client part and jump to source code, you can one click to jump to the official document

bsm.s3_client.put_object # select the put_object part and jump to source code, you can one click to jump to the official document
```

[image]

I checked the source code, it use boto_stub under the hood and enumerate all available client and explicitly give them type hint.

Hope this is helpful